# macOS: Keep XPC Service (bundled) running after user quits main app

Tags: c, macos, xpc

The bundled XPC Service in my macOS application need to do some post processing work with files dumped by the parent app, which most probably can't be completed within the usage time of the application. So, Is there a way to make the XPC service keep running even after the user quits the main app?

Answer (score 0):

You could install it as launch daemon (running in root context as long as computer is switched on) or as launch agent (running in user context as long as user is logged in).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should be using the `WatchPaths` or `QueueDirectories` feature of launchd.

> WatchPaths starts the job whenever any of the paths being watched have changed

or

> QueueDirectories  starts your job whenever the given directories are non-empty, and it keeps your job running as long as those directories are not empty

Both of these are covered by [Apple's launchd documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html).